# Multiline "for" "if"

Tags: python

I want to make this function with "for" multiline not single line like this. How to do it?

```
def stopwords_removal(words):
    return [word for word in words if word not in stopwords_indonesia]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a simple for loop and if statement to append items to the new list.

```
def stopwords_removal(words):
    newList = []
    for word in words:
        if word not in stopwords_indonesia:
            newList.append(word)
    return newList
```

However, I have no idea why you would want to do this instead of list comprehension. I would suggest sticking with that method.

Comment: Will have same output if I putting the `newList` outside function?

Comment: Yes, but you would have to reset newList (run `newList = []`) everytime you wanted to use the function again, so there's no point in doing that as it'd just add unnecessary steps.

Answer (score 1):

This should be fairly straight. You need a list to store the result in, expand the loop to its own line, the if to its own line, append to the original list, then return it.

```py
def stopwords_removal(words):
   res = []
   for word in words:
      if word not in stopwords_indonesia:
            res.append(word)

   return word
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you want

```
def stopwords_removal(words):
    random_list = []
    for word in words:
        if word not in stopwords_indonesia:
            random_list.append(word)
    return random_list
```